# How to get files between two commits in Azure Devops

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to get all files between two commits?

I tried to use

```
git diff <commitFrom>  <commitTo> Scripts/**/*.sql
```

and basically to archive later

```
git archive --output=artifact.zip HEAD (git diff <commitFrom>  <commitTo> UpdateScripts/**/*.sql)
```

I am getting empty artifact.zip file.

Also, I tried to use [Git Exec New SQL Files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=exclr8team.AHM-GitExecNewSQL&ssr=false#overview), but I am getting

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."
```

What is the best way to download all files added from specific commit to latest?

Is there any existing extension for Azure Devops?

How can I get all files as artifacts of the db build output?

UPDATE

Based on second answer:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.

      git archive --output=file.zip HEAD $(git diff --diff-filter=ACMRT --name-only ${{parameters.firstChangeset}}..${{parameters.secondChangeset}}  "Scripts/*.sql")
```

It does not filter folder.

Answer (score 0):

To get all files added you can use `--diff-filter=A` with `git diff`
and `--name-only` to only get the files name

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only sha1..sha2 "Scripts/**/*.sql"
```

`"` is to avoid to have your shell doing the expansion

Comment: Using PowerShell on my machine, this will give me desire changes, but if I use it as part of yaml file and PoweShell task, I am getting error: fatal: bad object ${{parameters.firstChangeset}}. I am getting solution zip.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any existing extension for Azure Devops?

Yes. I suggest that you can use the extension: [Git Copy Diff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ATP.ATP-GitCopyDiff) to get all changed files between commits and add them to folders.

Here are the steps to use the task:

Step1: Add git tag to the compare commit.

Step2: Define the current commit and tag of compare commit in the task.

For example:

```
- task: GitCopyDiff@7
  inputs:
    workingdir: '$(SYSTEM.DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/path'
    currentcommit: 'commitid'
    destination: '$(SYSTEM.ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY)'
    changeType: 'A,C,D,M,R,T'
    gittag: 'tag of the compare commit'
    nameOfFileDeletedList: 'FilesToBeDelete.ps1'
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error: ##[error]Something went wrong. Please check the logs.